# Output of content_for is not generated at desired position in HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, yield, content-for

**Rails: 3.0.11**

**Ruby: ruby 1.9.3dev (2011-09-23 revision 33323) [i686-linux]**

This is my custom layout file:

**custom_layout.html.haml**

```
!!!
%html{ :xmlns => "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", :"xml:lang" => "en", :lang => "en" }
  %head
    %meta{ :"http-equiv" => "Content-Type", :content => "text/html; charset=utf-8" }
    %title= SERVICE_NAME
    = render "shared/js_and_css"
  %body
    #wrapper.container_12
      #main.grid_12
        .grid_9.omega
          - flash.each do |name, message|
            = content_tag :p, message, :id => "flash_#{name}"
          = yield
        = yield :side_nav

    = render "layouts/footer"
```

View file: **personal_information.html.erb**

```
<div class="c1">
  <div class="c2">
    <div class="headings">
      <h1><%= t("general.edit_personal_information")%></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="info-area">
      <%= form_for @user, :html => { :multipart => true, :id => "user_form" }  do |f| %>
         <%= render :partial => "form", :object => f %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<% content_for :side_nav do %>
  <%= '<div class="grid_3 alpha">&nbsp;</div>'.html_safe  %>
<% end %>
```

Generated HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container_12" id="wrapper">
        <div class="grid_12" id="main">
            <div class="grid_9 omega">
                <div class="c1">
                  <div class="c2">
                    <div class="headings">
                        <h1>Edit profile</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="info-area">
                        <form>
                            <!-- FORM ELEMENTS HERE -->
                        </form>
                      </div>
                 </div>
                </div>     
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_3 alpha">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
```

The content set using **content_for :side_nav** is rendered AFTER **div id="wrapper"** instead of rendering after **div class="grid_9 omega"**. Can anybody please explain what is causing this weird behaviour and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `=` - you're just evaluating the code, but not assigning it to the view. This should fix it:

```
<%= content_for :side_nav do %>
  <%= '<div class="grid_3 alpha">&nbsp;</div>'.html_safe  %>
<% end %>
```

And you can get rid of the interpolation:

```
<%= content_for :side_nav do %>
  <div class="grid_3 alpha">&nbsp;</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: your suggestion didn't worked.It generates the same output as shown in my question above.